Cannot access Deno server using public IP. It is only available through localhost(loopback)
I built a server using both Apollo Server and the HTTP server module and I cannot access the servers outside my machine. I've made servers with both Node.JS and Dart and the problem seems to be exclusive to Deno.
How do I make my Deno server accessible online? I want to be able to access the server using my public IP.
const port = 8080;

const handler = (request: Request): Response => {

  return new Response("Hello World!", { status: 200 });
};

console.log(`HTTP server running. Access it at: http://localhost:8080/`);
Deno.serve({ 
  port,
}, handler);

